# Using Partial Least Squares as a generative model

Tags: machine-learning, partial-least-squares

0

The partial Least Squares (PLS) method is often used to model Latent Variable Regression (LVRs). At the end of the PLS algorithm, we have the loadings and scores. My question is, can we construct a model of the ideal X -> Y relationship from the loadings. For example, if the Y (target) variable in the simplest formulation is a 1D continuous variable, then is it allowed to interpret the X-loadings individually as the basis vectors of a space that are most correlated to Y?

So if I extrapolate the data along these vectors individually, will I get a generalized set of "ideal" X vectors that produce the Y values in the given range?

Comment: the ideal scores most correlated with y are y^hat scores from your classical OLS linear regression. I do not understand the rest of the question

Comment: Thanks. What I would like to know is if there is an ideal X associated with the Y. Can we invert the PLS model ask this question? Basically generate the X most likely to give rise to a particular value of y.